# limit records in mongodb query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is my document in `MongoDB` and I need to limit the output:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("55880fb8c3addd201ee2f70e"),
    "title": "Sales",
    "level1": [{
    "name": "Master",
    "link": "/sales/master"
    }, {
    "name": "eCommerce",
    "link": "/sales/ecommerce"
    }]
}
```

My search query is:

```
db.collection.find({
    title: "Sales",
    "level1.name": "Master"
}, {
    "title": 1,
    "level1.name": 1,
    "level1.name": "Master"
})
```

This is the expected output:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("55880fb8c3addd201ee2f70e"),
    "title": "Sales",
    "level1": [{
    "name": "Master",
    "link": "/sales/master"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) by  [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `level1` array to get expected result like following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$level1"},{$match:{"level1.name":"Master","title" :"Sales"}})
```

If you want all under one array you can group it like :

```
db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$level1"},{$match:{"title" :"Sales","level1.name":"Master"}},{$group:{_id:"_id","title":{$first:"$title"},"level1":{$push:"$level1"}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query :

```
 db.collection.find({title :"Sales",
                     level1: {$elematch: {name" : "Master"}}},
                    {title : 1, level1.$ : 1});
```

Comment: db.collection.find({"title":"Sales","level1":{"$elemMatch":{"name":{$in :["Master","eCommerce"]}}}},{"level1.$name":1,"title":1})...How to search for n no.of  $elematch

Comment: @AlnoorKhan The question has been asked many times before. Look at the linked duplicate answer at is has **all** your answers.